# Location of driver.conf used for DSBULK to load data into Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, dsbulk

I am using a configuration file as below to load data in Cassandra using DSBULK

```
include classpath("driver.conf")
dsbulk.connector.name="csv"
dsbulk.connector.csv.url="/my/datafile/"
dsbulk.connector.csv.delimiter=","
dsbulk.schema.keyspace="rajibks"
dsbulk.schema.table="rajibtable"
```

I wrote a python program to execute DSBULK using the above configuration. I noticed that i need to keep the dsbulk.conf in the DSBULK conf folder for the program to work. How do I specify a different location for the driver.conf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-f` command-line switch to specify location of the configuration file (see [doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/commonOptions.html#commonOptions__dashF)).  Location of `driver.conf` will be relative to this file.

Comment: Thanks, I used the -f for the config file, that works but it did not pick up the driver.conf which is in the same folder. Let me check my code one more time

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I got it working. I had the driver.conf and load_conf.conf under a folder called conf. In the load_conf.conf, instead of specifying include classpath("driver.conf"), i changed to include classpath("conf/driver.conf")